# How to center this table?

Tags: css, css-tables

How to center this table?

I have tried `margin-left: 50%` and `margin-right: 50%` but no result.

http://jsfiddle.net/WtJxT/ [1]

Note: Table columns must keep its original sizes, not to collapse.

[1]:

```
.tic {
    display : table; 
    width : 700px; 
    border:solid 7px #c9c9c9;
    height : 97%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tic
{
  display : table; 
  width : 700px; 
  border:solid 7px #c9c9c9;
  height : 97%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Why this works?**

As you can see I modified two attributes in your css snippet. First of all `postion: relative;`. Making the position relative makes the `div.tic` relative to it's parent container. The second attribute is `margin: 0 auto;`. The auto property tells the browser to set the margin so that the empty space between `tic` and it's outer container would be equal from both sides(left and right) and 0 sets the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to 0.

Comment: A short explanation would really improve this answer.